# How to get object for key from NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsdictionary

In dictionary named `dict` the key value pair is:

> "alba\U2019s window" = "A model in westindies.";

And to send `objectForKey:` I am getting the string like "alba's window". When I send like following:

> [dict objectForKey:alba's window];

I am not getting anything, it is showing null.

Comment: What if you do `[dict objectForKey:@"alba's window"];` or `[dict objectForKey:@"alba\U2019s window"];` ?

Answer (score 25):

For starters, you might want to make that an actual string, like so:

```
[dict objectForKey:@"alba's window"];
```

Note also that `\U2019` is not `'`; but `’`, which is a different character entirely.

And more generally, sticking to `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` for dictionary keys is probably a good idea, unless you are inserting and retrieving programmatically using the exact same string as a key.

Comment: i am using that only.it is displaying diff here.tell me for that only.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are referring to, or indeed what you are trying to say. Until I do, I cannot help you, unfortunately.

Comment: i got the solution ’ will not support in mac so i replaced with ' then it is working fine

Answer (score 9):

Since iOS6 onwards, a convenient method for setting and accessing the object for a key from an NSDictionary is:

```
//Setting the object in NSMutableDictionary
dictionary[@"someKey"] = @"someString";

//Accessing the object
NSString *str = dictionary[@"someKey"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `dict` isn't null; sending a message to a null object will silently fail and return `null`.

Another way to check your key/values is to simply `NSLog(@"%@",dict);` and this will show you the contents of the dictionary.  Note that this output only shows quotes around values when the value contains a space.

Also, make sure you're using the same pairs of strings as the key - it looks like you're using `"alba\U2019s window"` in addition to `"alba's window"`.