# access Object/Key-value pair from dictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
{
"b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334" : {
"57646099-b717-4a2b-b9eb-2935548ae954" : [
  "yes"
]
},
"1b186bc7-52c4-4b87-a97f-cc52054aad24" : {
"aba16653-bda0-4e89-b1c8-63df6faa7c10" : [
  "yes"
]
},
"d765038e-e85a-495d-9932-170852fbd86e" : {
"aba16653-bda0-4e89-b1c8-63df6faa7c10" : [
  "yes"
],
"57646099-b717-4a2b-b9eb-2935548ae954" : [
  "yes"
],
"957bdaba-b23d-4243-8384-62dfa46f0656" : "play"
},
"2a8dd370-2f7e-4c8e-93d5-21102fbc82fd" : {
"aba16653-bda0-4e89-b1c8-63df6faa7c10" : [
  "yes"
]
}
}
```

How to get each object say 
    "b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334" : {
    "57646099-b717-4a2b-b9eb-2935548ae954" : [
    "yes"
   ]
   }

OR 
    "d765038e-e85a-495d-9932-170852fbd86e" : {
    "aba16653-bda0-4e89-b1c8-63df6faa7c10" : [
    "yes"
    ],
    "57646099-b717-4a2b-b9eb-2935548ae954" : [
    "yes"
    ]

from this NSDictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get object for key from NSDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486907/how-to-get-object-for-key-from-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use for each in loop to get the full value. i.e

```
 let dict = your dictionary

 for each in dict {
     print(each)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `objectForKey:` to read the value for a key:

```
id value = [dict objectForKey:@"b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334"]
```

Which can be expressed more concisely using square bracket notation:

```
id value = dict[@"b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334"]
```

If you then want an object containing just that key mapped to its value then the easiest thing to do is just to construct a new object with the key and value:

```
id key = @"b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334";
id value = dict[key];
id result = @{ key: value }
```

Comment: [dict valueForKey:@"b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334"] will just give me  { "57646099-b717-4a2b-b9eb-2935548ae954" : [ "yes" ] }. But I need the whole object i.e.. key and its value as a whole

Comment: What exactly do you want then? I thought it was the whole object value.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you want to get back this: `{ "b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334":  { "57646099-b717-4a2b-b9eb-2935548ae954" : [ "yes" ] }}` ?

Comment: yes @julian  I need to get { "b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334": { "57646099-b717-4a2b-b9eb-2935548ae954" : [ "yes" ] }}

Comment: Use `objectForKey:` instead of `valueForKey:`. `dict[@"b3e0aded-d57b-4159-9c33-c8b006282334"]` does `objectForKey:`.